# numerical value of a unicode character in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode

is it possible to get a numerical value from a unicode character in objective-c?

@"A" is 0041, @"➜" is 279C, @"Ω" is 03A9, @"झ" is 091D... ?

Answer (score 7):

OK, so it’s perhaps worth pointing a few things out in a separate answer here.  First, the term “character” is ambiguous, so we should choose a more appropriate term depending on what we mean.  (See [Characters and Grapheme Clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html) in the Apple developer docs, as well as the [Unicode website](http://unicode.org) for more detail.)

**If you are asking for the UTF-16 *code unit***, then you can use

```
unichar ch = [myString characterAtIndex:ndx];
```

Note that this is *only* equivalent to a Unicode code-point in the case where the code point is within the Basic Multilingual Plane (i.e. it is less than U+FFFF).

**If you are asking for the Unicode *code point***, then you should be aware that UTF-16 supports characters outside of the BMP (i.e. U+10000 and above) using *surrogate pairs*.  Thus there will be *two* UTF-16 code units for any code point above U+10000.  To detect this case, you need to do something like

```
uint32_t codepoint = [myString characterAtIndex:ndx];

if ((codepoint & 0xfc00) == 0xd800) {
  unichar ch2 = [myString characterAtIndex:ndx + 1];

  codepoint = (((codepoint & 0x3ff) << 10) | (ch2 & 0x3ff)) + 0x10000;
}
```

Note that in production code, you should also test for and cope with the case where the surrogate pair has been truncated somehow.

**Importantly**, neither UTF-16 code units, nor Unicode code points necessarily correspond to anything that and end-user would regard as a “character” (the Unicode consortium generally refers to this as a *grapheme cluster* to distinguish it from other possible meanings of “character”).  There are many examples, but the simplest to understand are probably the combining diacritical marks.  For instance, the character ‘Ä’ can be represented as the Unicode code point U+00C4, or as a pair of code points, U+0041 U+0308.

Sometimes people (like @DietrichEpp in the comments on his answer) will claim that you can deal with this by converting to precomposed form before dealing with your string.  This is something of a red herring, because precomposed form only deals with characters that have a precomposed equivalent in Unicode.  e.g. it will not help with all combining marks; it will not help with Indic or Arabic scripts; it will not help with Hangul Jamos.  There are many other cases as well.

**If you are trying to manipulate *grapheme clusters*** (things the user might think of as “characters”), you should probably make use of the NSString methods `-rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:`, `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:` or the CFString function `CFStringGetRangeOfComposedCharactersAtIndex`.  Obviously you cannot hold a grapheme cluster in an integer variable and it has no inherent numerical value; rather, it is represented by a string of code points, which are represented by a string of code units.  For instance:

```
NSRange gcRange = [myString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:ndx];
NSString *graphemeCluster = [myString substringWithRange:gcRange];
```

Note that `graphemeCluster` may be arbitrarily long(!)

Even then, we have ignored the effects of matters such as Unicode’s support for bidirectional text.  That is, the order of the code points represented by the code units in your NSString *may* in some cases be the reverse of what you might expect.  The worse cases involve things like English text embedded in Arabic or Hebrew; this *is* supported by the Cocoa Text system, and so you really can end up with bidirectional strings in your code.

To summarise: **generally speaking one should avoid examining `NSString` and `CFString` instances unichar by unichar**.  If at all possible, use an appropriate `NSString` method or `CFString` function instead.  If you *do* find yourself examining the UTF-16 code units, please familiarise yourself with the Unicode standard first (I recommend “Unicode Demystified” if you can’t stomach reading through the Unicode book itself), so that you can avoid the major pitfalls.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that there's not one single "thing the user might think of as 'characters'". There are at least a couple of competing definitions: A pre-1980s person would probably define a character as a letter you write using a pen (this definition omits whitespace). A writer calls elements of the alphabet he uses characters, while a typographer might count a ligature like "ﬃ" one character instead of three. So the definition really depends on context. If you want to specify some value using one exact definition you should probably avoid the term (This question is proof).

Comment: Clarification: when I talk about “user” or “end-user” above, I’m really talking about a non-technical user unfamiliar with this area—i.e. not a programmer, Unicode expert or a typographer, but someone for whom the script under consideration is their native writing system.

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa strings allow you to access the UTF-16 elements using `-characterAtIndex:`, so the following code will convert the string to a unicode code point:

```
unsigned strToChar(NSString *str)
{
    unsigned c1, c2;
    c1 = [str characterAtIndex:0];
    if ((c1 & 0xfc00) == 0xd800) {
        c2 = [str characterAtIndex:1];
        return (((c1 & 0x3ff) << 10) | (c2 & 0x3ff)) + 0x10000;
    } else {
        return c1;
    }
}
```

I am not aware of any convenience functions for this.  You can use `-characterAtIndex:` by itself if you are okay with your code breaking horribly when someone uses characters outside the BMP; a number of applications on OS X break horribly in this way.

The following should render as a musical "G clef", U+1D11E, but if you copy and paste it into some text editors (TextMate), they'll let you do bizarre things like delete half of the character, at which point your text file is garbage.

Comment: There are surrogate pair to/from functions in the CFString stuff, but those do what your shifting does AFAIK.

Comment: Also, you need to be careful when doing these kinds of things because of the existence of combining marks and so on.  You can’t assume that a `0041` in an `NSString` is necessarily an ‘A’ rather than e.g. an ‘Ä’, nor will every encoding of ‘Ä’ necessarily contain the code `0041`.

Comment: @alastair: That's true, but if `"Ä"` is encoded with two code points, then it is technically two separate characters.  One can avoid this by using `-[NSString precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It is two separate *code units/code points*, and *not* two separate "characters".  The latter generally refers to things a user would think of as characters (so it is *one* character), though a rigorous discussion should really use a more well-defined concept such as the grapheme cluster.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Also, converting to canonical form only works for those characters for which a precomposed form is available.  It is not a general solution.

Comment: @alastair: If you read the Unicode standard, you will find that a "character" is just an abstract object corresponding to a single "code point".  If you insist on defining "character" in some method contrary to the way it is defined in the standard, then question is ill-defined.  For example, if we **redefine** it to mean "grapheme cluster", then the question becomes, "what is the numerical value of a grapheme cluster."  But no such mapping exists, it would have to be invented.  My solution works for all characters, you are simply changing the problem.

Comment: @alastair: Furthermore, use of "code unit" is also sloppy.  The fact that `"Ä"` may be represented with two code points, and those two code points may be encoded with two code units, is entirely coincidental and only works in UTF-16 and UTF-32.  Code units are properties of the *encoding*, not of the character, and a two-character representation of `"Ä"` will require three code units in UTF-8.  These terms (character, code unit) are already well-defined and I am not inventing any definitions here.

Comment: @DietrichEpp To quote the Unicode consortium: “The very term character is rather ambiguous, and may be interpreted broadly or narrowly.”  Character *DOES NOT* correspond to a code point, as is explicitly stated in UTR#17: “there are not necessarily one-to-one relationships between characters and code points”.

Comment: @alastair: Look at http://www.unicode.org/glossary/ -- "character" has no less than four definitions, including "(3) The basic unit of encoding for the Unicode character encoding." which is what programmers interact with here.  Indeed you are right that it "may be interpreted broadly or narrowly", and I interpreted it narrowly because that is the only interpretation that gives the question a well-defined answer.  If you want to provide an *alternative answer* go ahead.  If you think the body my answer is *not helpful* then vote it down.  Quibbling over definitions of "character" is pointless.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The fact that “character” is ambiguous is very important to anyone reading this question and your answer.  Asserting that it is equivalent to “code point” is patently false, since the latter is not ambiguous.

Comment: I think both of you provided some helpful information here and it's not really about being right or wrong. What your discussion really points out is: Strings are complex and it's difficult to define what a character is. (I always found it misleading that Cocoa's `NSString` calls its elements "character".)