# Find and replace long words in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to write a method that will search an NSString, determine if an individual word within the string is over 6 characters long and replace that word with some other word (something arbitrary like 'hello').

I am starting with a long paragraph and I need to end up with a single NSString object whose format and spacing has not been affected by the find and replace.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's very difficult to understand what your question really is. Any tried code snippet would be great.

Comment: How on Earth did this question get closed? Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Monolo The first two votes occurred before the edits (when the question really was in a bad state). Since there's no way to vote against close-votes any question that has a single close-vote will eventually be closed. People just stumble over these posts in the review section and close them without caring too much for what went on before the first close-votes went in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Why another answer?

There are a couple of subtle problems with the simple solutions using `componentsSeparatedByString:`:

1. Punctuation is not handled as word delimiters.
2. Whitespace other that the space character (newline, tab) is simply dropped.
3. On long strings a lot of memory is wasted.
4. It's slow.

#### Example

Assuming a substitution word of "–" a string like ...

> “Essentially,” the D.H.C. concluded,
>   ”bokanovskification consists of a series of arrests of development.”

... would result in ...

> – the D.H.C. – – of a series of – of –

... while the correct output would be:

> “–,” the D.H.C. –,
> ”– – of a series of – of –.”

#### Solution

Fortunately there's a much better, yet simple solution in Cocoa: `-[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]`

It provides fast iteration over substrings defined by the `options` argument. One possibility is the `NSStringEnumerationByWords` which enumerates all substrings that are actually real words (in the current locale). It even detects individual words in languages that don't use delimiters (spaces) to separate words, like japanese.

#### Comparing Solutions

[Here's a simple demo project](https://gist.github.com/NikolaiRuhe/5546537) that works on the jargon file (1.6 MB, 237,239 words). It compares three different solutions:

1. componentsSeparatedByString: 270 ms
2. enumerateSubstringsInRange: 125 ms
3. stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString, as described by @Monolo: 200 ms

#### Implementation

The core of it is the replacement loop:

```
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[originalString length]];
__block NSUInteger location = 0;
[originalString enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange){0, [originalString length]}
                                   options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized | NSStringEnumerationSubstringNotRequired
                                usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {

                                    if (substringRange.length > maxChar) {
                                        NSString *charactersBetweenLongWords = [originalString substringWithRange:(NSRange){ location, substringRange.location - location }];
                                        [result appendString:charactersBetweenLongWords];
                                        [result appendString:replaceWord];
                                        location = substringRange.location + substringRange.length;
                                    }

                                }];
[result appendString:[originalString substringFromIndex:location]];
```

#### Caveat

As pointed out by [Monolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644348/monolo) the proposed code uses `NSString`'s length to determine the number of characters of a word. That's a questionable approach, to say the least. In fact a string's `length` specifies the number of code fragments used to encode the string, a value that often defers from what a human would assume the number of characters.

As the term "character" has different meanings in various contexts and the OP didn't specify which kind of character count to use I just leave the code as it was. If you want a different count please refer to the documentation that discusses the topic:

- Apple's String Programming Guide, [Characters and Grapheme Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html)
- Unicode FAQ: [How are characters counted when measuring the length or position of a character in a string?](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#7)

Comment: Just to nitpick, if you consider the word "Ålborg" encoded with the use of a compound character, like this: @"A\u030Alborg", your implementation will trigger the substitution. `substringRange` of course only considers the "raw" (for want of a better word) characters. I have tried it with a function that counts compound chars, and it still works, but I don't what the fasted method to count compound characters is. (Oh and it is a bank holiday here, so time for academic studies :-))

Comment: @Monolo Very good finding, thanks for pointing this bug out! Composed character sequences, surrogate pairs and consonant clusters are a common source of a lot of bugs in string processing code. Apple's "String Programming Guide, Characters and Grapheme Clusters" is an excellent read, as usual: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html

Comment: @Monolo Upvoted some random answers of yours (in lack of comment upvote reputation).

Comment: Here is a question with [alastair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/346335/alastair)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16693106/644348) providing some useful details in a handy form.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the answers, there are several ways to accomplish what you are after, but personally I prefer to use the `NSString` class's `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` method, which is made exactly to replace substrings with another string.

In your case we need to use the `NSRegularExpressionSearch` option which will allow to identify words with 7 or more letters (i.e., more than 6 letters as you state it).

If you use the `\w`<sup>*</sup> character expression you will automatically get Unicode support, so it works on as many languages as Apple (actually, ICU) supports.

It goes like this:

```
NSString *stringWithLongWords = @"There are some words of extended length in this text. One of them is Escher's. They will be identified with a regular expression and changed for some arbitrary word.";

NSString *overSixCharsPattern = @"(?w)\\b[\\w]{7,}\\b";
NSString *replacementString   = @"hello";

NSString *result = [stringWithLongWords stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: overSixCharsPattern
                                                                  withString: replacementString
                                                                     options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                       range: NSMakeRange(0, stringWithLongWords.length)];
```

The `\b` expressions denote a word boundary, which ensures that the whole word is matched and substituted. The `w` modifier makes `\b` use a more natural definition of word boundaries. Specifically, it handles the string "Escher's", the example mentioned by @NikolaiRuhe. Docs [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), with a specific discussion of boundary detection [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis).

Also notice that a literal `NSString` (i.e., one you type directly in your Objective-C source file) needs two backslashes in the source code to produce one in the generated string.

There is more information in the [NSString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

<sup>*</sup> Technically `\w` matches word characters, which also includes numbers in the definition used by regexes.

Comment: There are a couple of interesting differences between the regex word detection and the one `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` uses. regex consider "Escher's" two words while the Cocoa text system sees it as one. Domain or file names like "think.com" or "AIWORD.RF" are treated similar.

Comment: Performance is in the middle between the `componentsSeparatedByString` and the `enumerateSubstringsInRange` variants.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe While I deliberately didn't consider performance (premature optimisation and all that), I can see how one would like to have it detect genitives and contractions ("it's") in English. In my defense I'd venture that it works satisfactorily on Norwegian text :-) I guess I should begin considering `enumerateSubstrings...` and friends. OTOH, whether I'd expect it to identify an internet domain name as a word or not is a philosophical question that will require at least a glass of good wine to analyse.

Comment: I agree. I just found the fact interesting that enumerateSubstrings seems to use a more sophisticated model of language and thus identifies delimiters in a different way. I found that Apple's string manipulation functions are usually simple to use yet **very** advanced below the surface.