# How can I replace certain words in a sentence with other words while maintaining the correct capitalization efficiently?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

As detailed in this previous answer,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458627/1633251, it appears that `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` is much faster than separating the string into an array with some guessed at punctuation characters. However, what I don't understand is how I can efficiently maintain the correct capitalization and punctuation (but ignoring punctuation within words i.e. apostrophes). Note I'm fairly new to Objective-C.

Specifically, I have this string: `@"My computer is on fire! What should I do? I need my computer's files!"` and I want to change every word longer than 5 characters to "boss" while preserving capitalization: `@"My boss is on boss! Boss boss I do? I boss my boss boss!"`

Comment: @"My computer is on fire! What should I do?" - Tell everyone it was on fire when you found it.

Comment: What is the problem with the function as it is?  Providing an example of what you want it to output and what is actually being output would be very helpful for those of us trying to help you.

Comment: Made the edit for the output I'm going for.

Comment: Write down how you'd tell someone to do the job with pencil and paper, if they had no understanding of English or punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that will do what you want, updated to handle numbers:

```
NSString *original = @"My computer is on fire at 9:00 AM! What should I do?";
NSString *swapString = @"boss";

NSMutableString *modified = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[original length]];
__block NSUInteger lastCharOffset = 0;

[original enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [original length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords // NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences // | NSStringEnumerationSubstringNotRequired
    usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop)
        {
            //NSLog(@"SUBSTRING %@", substring);

            NSString *replaceString = substring;
            if([substring length] > 2) {
                unichar origChar = [substring characterAtIndex:0];
                if(![[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:origChar]) {
                    replaceString = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:origChar] ? [swapString capitalizedString] : swapString;
                }
            }
            if(substringRange.location) {
                [modified appendString:[original substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(lastCharOffset, substringRange.location-lastCharOffset)]];
            }
            [modified appendString:replaceString];
            lastCharOffset = substringRange.location + substringRange.length;
        } ];
        // Grab any trailing punctuation
        [modified appendString:[original substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(lastCharOffset, [original length] - lastCharOffset)]];
    NSLog(@"Orig: %@", original);
    NSLog(@"Modi: %@", modified);
```

The output is:

```
Orig: My computer is on fire at 9:00 AM! What should I do?
Modi: My boss is on boss at 9:00 AM! Boss boss I do?
```

Comment: This does not deal with the capitalization problem. I have already fixed that problem. After testing this method on other strings, it also converts any numbers longer than 2 digits to the word `boss`. Do you know any way to stop it from doing that?

Comment: Yes, it deals with capitalization - here:                replaceString = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:origChar] ? [substring capitalizedString] : subString;
If its a number, then you need to test if the first character is a digit. that was not in your original question. If you have a really complex problem it will require a complex answer! If you looked at the NSLogs you'd see that your original string was changed as you wanted!

Comment: Sorry it does work, as long as your change `[substring capitalizedString]` to `[subString capitalizedString]`.

Comment: So why is this the accepted answer if it has the very same bug as your original code?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have two different variables that look nearly identical – `substring` and `subString` (note the different capitalization).

`substring` is the current word in the block, while `subString` is always `@"boss"`. When you set `replaceString`, you only use `subString` for lowercase words (replacing the words with `@"boss"`), but `substring` for uppercase words (essentially replacing the words with themselves). So the result is that your method works for replacing lowercase words with a different lowercase word, but it doesn't seem to do anything with uppercase words.

Comment: So I've fixed that problem now. The only other problem I'm having is that when I test this method with other strings it does not ignore numbers within the string. Know any way around that?

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about word replacement as distinct from intra-word substring replacement: I would tokenize on white-space, and thereby include any punctuation as part of the tokenized word. E.g."fire!".

If you want to replace "fire" with "steroids" and retain all original capitalization and punctuation, you would note that "steroids" begins with lower-case and has an exclamation point, so you replace the alphabetic string "fire" with "steroids" and append the puntuation point.

The question then becomes: "Given a single word that might begin with upper or lower case, and might have punctuation, how best to distinguish between punctuation and alphabetic characters, and how best to determine whether the initial character is in upper or lower case?"

Comment: Note that tokenizing on white space is a bad idea if you want to support multiple languages (eg Chinese).  Using his existing method to break words is the correct approach.

Comment: What you're saying is what I'm trying to accomplish, sorry about the phrasing. Given what you have said, what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: @Inafziger: how are word-boundaries defined in Chinese writing systems? My familiarity is with western writing systems only. Also, does Chinese writing have the concept upper/lower case?